# When completing your About Me section, notifications are received from multiple sites

Tags: bug, notifications

I know my profile is shown on multiple sites, but I don't think so many notifications are necessary. So far I've received the following notification:

> You've earned the "Autobiographer" badge (Complete "About Me" section of user profile).

From pretty much every Stack Exchange site that I've visited.

Comment: What notification are you talking about?

Comment: `You've earned the "Autobiographer" badge (Complete "About Me" section of user profile).`

Comment: This badge is awarded for completing your profile, which - when transferred to other sites - gives you the badge there as well. As it stands right now, this seems to be the intended behavior, and this question should probably be a [meta-tag:feature-request] to suppress notifications about the same badge on multiple sites or combine them into one in this case.

Comment: The badge on all sites sure, but the notification should only come from a single site - e.g. meta or the site the completing profile change was submitted from.